# How to deploy CUDA programs on Windows?

Tags: windows, deployment, cuda

I have a program linking against `cuda`, `cublas`, and `cudart`.

Is there a way to deploy it without forcing the users to install the very latest nvidia drivers?

When I just copy the mentioned dlls into the startup path, the program doesn't start and complains about a non-existent procedure in `nvcuda.dll`. Even if I supply this one as well, the program behaves strangely. If the most recent drivers are installed, everything works fine.

Related question ... how can I check that cuda is supported (+ up to date) and if this is not the case fallback into my case BLAS/LAPACK? If I provide the dlls the prog. misbehaves, if I don't supply them it might not even start.

Thx!

Comment: There's a function [`cudaGetDeviceCount`](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g665468e8cb33be42434f11bee2684ec9.html) that you can use to check at runtime if you have a device.

Comment: Right, but I need all dlls in place before in order to start - don't I? So I will have to supply them with my program. But then if there is a version conflict between the dlls supplied by me and the installed stuff ... things start to get nasty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try not to link against CUDA dlls, but load dynamically and call cudaGetDeviceCount()? Like this:

```
typedef cudaError_t (*FnGetDeviceCount )    (   int *   count    ) ;
HMODULE hCuda=LoadLibrary("cudart32_40_17.dll");
if( !hCuda ) return ; // ERROR: cannot load dll, DllMain must have failed because cudart only depends on Kernel dll implicitly. Or cannot find dll in curent directory or in the path.
FnGetDeviceCount fnGetDeviceCount=(FnGetDeviceCount)GetProcAddress(hCuda, "cudaGetDeviceCount");
if( !fnGetDeviceCount) return; // ERROR: cudart has no entry point for cudaGetDeviceCount ?!
int count = 0;
if( cudaSuccess != (*fnGetDeviceCount)(&count) ) return ;// ERROR: we don't wanna use CUDA if even device enumeration fails
if( !count ) return; // FALLBACK: CUDA has no devices, don't try to use it, fallback to some other BLAS
```

It's inconvenient because you can't just link against cudart or other libraries, but it may allow you to fallback to BLAS without user seeing horrible startup errors. Disclaimer: I didn't test or even compile this code, please let us know if you use it and it works :)

[This thread](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=162657) suggests you have to redistribute dlls from your particular version of the CUDA toolkit (e.g. cudart64_40_17.dll), so that's fine.